# Polynomial bijections from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, rational-numbers

**Prove or Improve**: Polynomials $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ which induce a bijection $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ are linear.

The question of existence of a polynomial bijection $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ is open, as discussed in this [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q), this [post by Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/06/08/ruling-out-polynomial-bijections-over-the-rationals-via-bombieri-lang/), and many more places. However, I cannot find much about the simpler question of polynomial bijections $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ (probably because this is easier and less interesting). Here are a few somewhat immediate observations:

- One quickly notes that any such bijection can always be put in the form
  $$a_nx^n+\dots+a_1x$$ for $a_1,\dots,a_n\in \mathbb{Z}$ by composing with an appropriate linear polynomial. From there, I have tried to use the rational root theorem to obtain some sort of result, but to no avail.
- Note that, unlike the $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ case, it is quite easy to obtain an injection. For example, $f(x)=x^3+x$ is clearly injective, but unfortunately fails to be surjective ($f(x)=1$ yields $x^3+x-1=0$, which has only irrational roots by the rational root theorem, hence $1$ has no rational inverse).

Is this a known result, and if so, how would one prove it? Or is there some higher order bijective polynomial on $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Here’s how one can use your strategy: Take a prime $p$. By precomposing with $p^{-m}x$ for large enough $m$, and multiplying the resulting polynomial by the reciprocal of the highest-degree monomial, you can get your polynomial to be monic, with all coeffs divisible by $p$. Then this polynomial never takes the value $p$, by Eisenstein.

Comment: relevant (though stronger, being about surjections): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027517/existence-of-a-surjective-non-linear-polynomial-p-in-bbb-qx/1027556#1027556

Comment: Do you mean *disprove*?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish no, I did mean prove or improve! Improve -> fix the statement, but in this case it was already correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume $f(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots +a_1x+a_0\in\Bbb Q[x]$ with $a_n\ne0$ induces a surjection $\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q$.
Let $p$ be a large prime such that $|a_i|_p=1$ for all non-zero $a_i$. Then $$|f(x)|_p\le\max\{\,|a_kx^k|_p\mid k\ge0\,\}=\max\{\,|x|^k_p\mid a_k\ne 0\,\}$$ with equality if these are distinct, i.e., if $|x|_p\ne 1$. In particular, either $|x|_p\le 1$ and so $|f(x)|_p\le 1$, or $|x|_p\ge p$ and so $|f(x)|_p\ge p^n$. For surjectivity, we need some $x\in\Bbb Q$ with $|f(x)|_p=p$. Therefore we need $n\le 1$.

Comment: Succinct, clear and yet stronger than the required result. Thank you!

Comment: What is the $|\cdot|_p$ notation?

Comment: @aschepler it is the [$p$-adic norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html)

Answer (score 6):

Here’s yet another effort:

We may assume that our polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]$ is monic, just by dividing the whole polynomial by the coefficient of the highest-degree term $x^d$.

Now let $p$ be a prime not dividing any of the numerators of the coefficients of $f$. I claim that there is no $z\in\Bbb Q$ with $f(z)=1/p$. It’s the proof of Eisenstein upside-down:

Let $z=m/n$, with coprime integers $m$ and $n$. If $p\nmid n$, then $p\nmid f(z)$, while if $p\mid n$, then $p^d$ is exactly the power of $p$ dividing the numerator of $f(z)$. (In $p$-adic language, if $v_p(z)\ge0$, then $v_p(f(z))\ge0$, while if $v_p(z)<0$, then $v_p(f(z))=dv_p(z)$.)

In any case, the numerator of $f(z)$ can not be only singly divisible by $q$.

Comment: Your $v_p$ sentence is fine but the divides and numerators sentences are weird

Comment: If you’d like to clean up the language to make it clearer, @reuns , I won’t feel hurt.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Hilbert irreducibility theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_irreducibility_theorem): let $p(X) \in \mathbb Q[X]$ be such a polynomial, and consider the polynomial

$$f(Q,X) = p(X) + Q\in\mathbb Q(Q)[X].$$

This is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(Q)$: by [Gauss' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) it is irreducible as soon as it is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[Q,X] = \mathbb Q[X][Q]$, and as a polynomial in $Q$ it is monic and linear.

As the conditions for the Hilbert irreducibility theorem are met, it can be concluded that there exists a $q\in\mathbb Q$ such that $f(q,X)$ is irreducible. In particular $p(X) + q$ does not have a rational root, so $-q$ is not in the image.

Comment: Is it clear that $f(Q,X)$ must always be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(Q)$?

Comment: By [Gauss' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)) we only have to consider factors in $\mathbb Q[Q][X] = \mathbb Q[X][Q]$. As a polynomial in $Q$ over $\mathbb Q[X]$ it is linear and monic, hence trivially irreducible.

Comment: I'll edit that into the answer

Answer (score 2):

First, we may assume that $P$ has integer coefficients, as we may just scale it up by any factor.

**Claim.** There exist infinitely many primes $p$ for which there exist $a$ and $b$ so that $p|P(a)-P(b)$, but $p\nmid a-b$.

First, we see that this finishes. Take some such prime $p$ greater than the leading coefficient of $P$, and consider the set of integers reached by taking $P(m)\bmod p$ for any integer $m$. This set cannot be all of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb Z$, since $P(x)\equiv P(x+p)\bmod p$ for any $x$ and $P(a)\equiv P(b)$ as well. So, there is some integer $i$ so that $P(x)\not\equiv i\bmod p$ for any $x\in\mathbb Z$.

Now, assume that $P(q)=i$ for some rational $q$. If $q$ has no factors of $p$ in its denominator, then $q$ is equivalent to $m\bmod p$ for some integer $m$, and
$$P(q)\equiv P(m)\not\equiv i\bmod p.$$
However, if $q$ has some factors of $p$ in its denominator, then $P(q)$ must have $p^{\operatorname{deg}P}$ in its denominator, since $p$ can't divide $P$'s leading coefficient.

Now all that's left is to prove the claim.

*Proof.* Assume for the sake of contradiction that there are only finitely many such primes, and that they are all less than some $N$. Pick some integer $c$. A prime $p>N$ may only divide $P(x)-P(c)$ if $p|x-c$. As a result, the only primes that can divide $P(p+c)-P(c)$ are primes less than $N$ and the prime $p$.

We claim that there exist some $a,b$ so that $P(p+c)-P(c)=ap^b$ for infinitely many primes $p$. Let $t$ be the product of all primes less than $N$, and let $u$ be some number relatively prime to $t$ so that $P(c+u)\neq P(c)$. Now, let $T$ be some large power of $t$ so that $$\nu_q(P(c+u)-P(c))<\nu_q(T).$$ For any integer $k$,
$$P(c+Tk+u)-P(c)\equiv P(c+u)-P(c)\bmod T,$$
so
$$\nu_q\left(P(c+Tk+u)-P(c)\right)=\nu_q\left(P(c+u)-P(c)\right);$$
as a result, if $Tk+u$ is a prime $p$,
$$P(p+c)-P(c) \big| \left(P(c+u)-P(c)\right)p^B$$
for some integer $B$. Write $P(p+c)-P(c)=ap^b$ with $p\nmid a$; we will show that both $a$ and $b$ are bounded. For large $p$, $P(p+c)-P(c)$ is bounded by $p^{\deg P+1}$, so $b$ must be in $\{0,1,\dots,\deg P\}$. Also, $a$ must be one of the finitely many divisors of $P(p+c)-P(c)$. So, by the infinite pigeonhole principle, there exists some pair $(a,b)$ so that there are infinitely many primes $p$ for which $P(p+c)-P(c)=ap^b$, and so $P(x+c)-P(c)=ap^b$.

Now, we have
$$P(x)-P(0)=a_0x^{b_0}\text{ and }P(x+1)-P(1)=a_1x^{b_1}.$$
It is clear that $a_0=a_1$ and $b_0=b_1$ by comparing leading terms, so $P(x+1)-P(1)=P(x)-P(0)$, which means $P$ is linear, a contradiction.

Firstly, we may replace $P(x)$ with $P(x)-P(0)$ so that $P(0)=0$. Thus, we get that a prime $p$ can divide $P(x)$ if and only if $p|x$. As a result, $P(p)$ is a power of $p$ for any large prime $p$; as $P(x)$ is bounded by $x^{\deg P+1}$ for large $x$, there are finitely many possible exponents, so there must exist some positive integer $n$ for which $P(p)=p^n$ for infinitely many primes $p$, whence $P(x)=x^n$ everywhere. However, by repeating the same process at $P(1)$ instead of $P(0)$, we have that
$$P(x)-P(1)=(x-1)^k$$
as well for some $k$; these cannot both be true.

Comment: Your proof paragraph has many problems

Comment: @reuns You're right -- I'll fix it.

Comment: @reuns I've updated the proof; hopefully it's right now.